# Any reason scrollbars=yes would not work?

Tags: javascript

I have this function which is supposed to open up a child window using Javascript. I'm doing it this way:

```
 if (a == "culture") {
    newWindow = window.open('criteria.php?type=culture','','scrollbars=yes,width=400,height=300');
    newWindow.focus();
}
                else if (a == "service") {
         newWindow = window.open('criteria.php?type=service','','scrollbars=yes,width=400,height=300');
newWindow.focus();
                }
```

However, the scrollbars never appear - and I can't figure out why. I've been asked to include them, as my windows don't work well without them (they're obviously a small size, and with dynamic content, this size can quickly get expanded on)

How do I fix the scroll issue? Why does scrollbars=yes not work?

Comment: Hmmm, have you paid your browser this week? Maybe he's disgruntled (Friday crappy humour, kindly forgive).

Comment: @AndrewAlexander: Do you have a link to an example?

Comment: Sadly, I don't, it's all on private company areas.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On some browsers scrollbars are only shown when the content is too long for the height.

If your current content does not exceed `300px`, then they will not be shown.

The default for `scrollbars` is `yes` anyway, so you don't need to specify this parameter.

Comment: The problem being that the content can exceed 300px, dynamically. Would the solution then be to check for whether scrollbars should be added using Javascript upon each new addition or deletion of content?

Comment: The scrollbars should automatically appear once the content exceeds 300px. You shouldn't need to put any javascript in place, the browser will handle this functionality for you. On older browsers like IE6 the scrollbar is there all the time, even when not needed. With newer browsers, like Google Chrome, the scrollbar automatically appears once the content reaches an exceeded length.

Comment: Try testing with long content, you should see a scrollbar